# UDP multicast sending on wrong NIC (Java, Mac OS X)

Tags: java, macos, udp, multicast

While working on a Java application under Mac OS X (Lion, 10.7.2, Java version "1.6.0_29"), I'm running into a strange problem while trying to send multicast UDP datagrams. The packets are only being sent on one NIC, and I have no control over which one.

The following example code illustrates what I am trying to do:

```
public class MCast {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InetAddress multicastAddr = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
        int port = 58680;
        byte[] data = "test".getBytes();

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, multicastAddr, port);

        MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();
        socket.joinGroup(multicastAddr);
        socket.setNetworkInterface(NetworkInterface.getByName("en0"));

        socket.send(packet);
        System.out.println("Packet sent.");
    }
}
```

Whilst executing this code, I am using Wireshark to examine all the traffic going out on en0. No packets are sent on the port specified. However, said packets do appear on the trace for en1.

When I disable en1, the packets go out on en0 properly.

I'm at a loss here. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a an address to the constructor of MulticastSocket. You can use it to bind it to the address you want.

Comment: Ordinarily, that would do the job. Unfortunately, the nature of the service I'm writing requires that it be on a port already in use by another application, and attempting to bind to it throws a `BindException`. Thanks for trying, though. EDIT: Or I can use my brain and tell it to bind with a port of 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Multicast output interface is decided by the current routing table at the time you do the group join. In most cases that means default route, hence the `en0`. Adding an explicit route would help, but you can just reverse the two lines in your code to be:

```
socket.setNetworkInterface(NetworkInterface.getByName("en0"));
socket.joinGroup(multicastAddr);
```

Also, you don't need to join (nor `bind()`) the group if you are only sending and not listening to that multicast traffic. Instead, `connect()` to the group address.